# How can I define elements positions in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS and I've came across the following question.

I need to insert a vertical gap between the elements of the site::

[image: Image01]

To be like that:

[image: Image01]

But I have no idea to get it done without using a lot of `<br>`.

Can someone help me to get this done?

Thanks so much!

Comment: you need to learn html and css basics. it's easy. and you can do that using margin or padding. you can start here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Comment: it's always better to try your best, then if you can't, just post your code here in a snippet. then we can help.

Comment: As @Willpower-7 says, margin or padding is what you're after https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just add a margin to your html element that contains your 'Header' text, and some margins to the button.

This is a good resource for that: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 0):

`gap` style property is for `display: flex`, but you can use `margin-bottom` for this, here is an example.

#### HTML

```html
<div>
 <div class="header">
   <h2>Header</h2>
 </div>
 <h1>Header</h1>
<div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.header {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your reply.

And if in the right side of my website I want to add an element between the Header text and the Header element?

Tks so much

Comment: just add it in html, try using display flex

Answer (score 0):

you can also insert in a line break with the br tag
`<br>`

Comment: For this question I would not recommend using `<br>`